# ¿Por que los registros se muestran nulos?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, gson

Muy buenos días tengan colegas, quisiera saber si alguien tiene alguna idea de porque los registros se muestran nulos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi JSON tiene datos los cuales son los siguientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el script que estoy utilizando para realizar la base de datos interna de SQLite

```
public static final String SCRIPT_TABLE_2 = " " +
        "create table "+TABLE_2+" " +
        "(" +
        "id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        "concesionario varchar(75), " +
        "cable_instalar varchar(120), " +
        "Tipo_Red varchar(45) not null " +
        "); ";
```

Estos son los métodos para registrar y obtener los registros.

```
public boolean insertSolicitud(ItemSolicitud itemSolicitud){
    AD = DB.getWritableDatabase();
    boolean result = false;

    ContentValues CV = new ContentValues();
    CV.put("concesionario", itemSolicitud.getConcesionario());
    CV.put("cable_instalar", itemSolicitud.getCable_instalar());
    CV.put("Tipo_Red", itemSolicitud.getTipo_Red());

    try {
        result = AD.insert(DataBase.TABLE_2,null,CV) > 0;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AD.close();
    return result;
}

public ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> getAllSolicitudes(){
    ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> lstSlicitud = new ArrayList<ItemSolicitud>();

    AD = DB.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor myCursor = AD.query(DataBase.TABLE_2, new String[]{
                    "id","concesionario","cable_instalar","Tipo_Red"},
            null,null,null,null,null);
    if (myCursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            lstSlicitud.add(new ItemSolicitud(myCursor.getInt(0),
                    myCursor.getString(1)));
        }while (myCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    AD.close();
    return lstSlicitud;
}
```

dejo las siguientes clases que complementan esta actividad

mi adaptador

```
public class AdapterSolicitud extends BaseAdapter {

protected AppCompatActivity datosActivity;
protected ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> itemSolicitudes;

public AdapterSolicitud (AppCompatActivity datosActivity, ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> itemSolicitudes){
    this.datosActivity = datosActivity;
    this.itemSolicitudes = itemSolicitudes;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemSolicitudes.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return itemSolicitudes.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)datosActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inf.inflate(R.layout.item_solicitudes, null);
    }

    ItemSolicitud myItemSolicitudes = itemSolicitudes.get(i);
    TextView txtCon, txtCable, txtTipo;

    txtCon = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCon);
    txtCable = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCable);
    txtTipo = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtTipo);

    txtCon.setText("Concesionario: " + myItemSolicitudes.getConcesionario());
    txtCable.setText("Cable a instalar: " + myItemSolicitudes.getCable_instalar());
    txtTipo.setText("Tipo de red: " + myItemSolicitudes.getTipo_Red());
    return v;
}
```

}

mi constructor

```
public class ItemSolicitud implements Serializable {
int id;
String concesionario, cable_instalar, Tipo_Red;

public ItemSolicitud(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ItemSolicitud(int id, String concesionario) {
    this.id = id;
    this.concesionario = concesionario;
}

public ItemSolicitud(int id, String concesionario, String cable_instalar) {
    this.id = id;
    this.concesionario = concesionario;
    this.cable_instalar = cable_instalar;
}

public ItemSolicitud(int id, String concesionario, String cable_instalar, String tipo_Red) {
    this.id = id;
    this.concesionario = concesionario;
    this.cable_instalar = cable_instalar;
    Tipo_Red = tipo_Red;
}

public ItemSolicitud(String concesionario, String cable_instalar, String tipo_Red) {
    this.concesionario = concesionario;
    this.cable_instalar = cable_instalar;
    Tipo_Red = tipo_Red;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getConcesionario() {
    return concesionario;
}

public void setConcesionario(String concesionario) {
    this.concesionario = concesionario;
}

public String getCable_instalar() {
    return cable_instalar;
}

public void setCable_instalar(String cable_instalar) {
    this.cable_instalar = cable_instalar;
}

public String getTipo_Red() {
    return Tipo_Red;
}

public void setTipo_Red(String tipo_Red) {
    Tipo_Red = tipo_Red;
}
```

}

y la clase principal

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_solicitudes);

```
    lstSolicitud = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstSolicitudes);
    myItemSolicitud = new ArrayList<ItemSolicitud>();

    myDaoSolicitud = new DaoSolicitudes(getApplication());
    myItemSolicitud = myDaoSolicitud.getAllSolicitudes();

    myAdapterSolicitud = new AdapterSolicitud(this, myItemSolicitud);
    lstSolicitud.setAdapter(myAdapterSolicitud);
    registerForContextMenu(lstSolicitud);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0,0,0, "Actualizar");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case 0:
            new SolicitudSegundoplano().execute("");
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

public void reload(){
    myDaoSolicitud = new DaoSolicitudes(getApplicationContext());
    myItemSolicitud = myDaoSolicitud.getAllSolicitudes();
    myAdapterSolicitud = new AdapterSolicitud(this, myItemSolicitud);
    lstSolicitud.setAdapter(myAdapterSolicitud);
}

public ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> LanzarSolicitud(String params){
    METHOD_NAME = "getConDetail";
    SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

    ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> myArrayWS = new ArrayList<ItemSolicitud>();

    try {

        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        concesionario = new PropertyInfo();
        concesionario.setName("solicitud");
        concesionario.setValue(params);
        concesionario.setType(String.class);

        request.addProperty(concesionario);

        envelo = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelo.dotNet = false;
        envelo.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_SERVICE);
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelo);

        String resultado = (String) envelo.getResponse();

        Type tipo = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ItemSolicitud>>() {}.getType();

        Gson convertidoJson = new Gson();

        myArrayWS = convertidoJson.fromJson(resultado, tipo);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return myArrayWS;
}

class SolicitudSegundoplano extends AsyncTask<String,Integer, ArrayList<ItemSolicitud>>{

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> doInBackground(String... params) {
        return LanzarSolicitud(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialogAsynk = ProgressDialog.show(Solicitudes.this, "", "Cargando...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> itemSolicituds) {
        super.onPostExecute(itemSolicituds);

        dialogAsynk.dismiss();

        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Tamaño del arrego: " + itemSolicituds.size());

        DaoSolicitudes myDao = new DaoSolicitudes(getApplicationContext());

        for (ItemSolicitud solicitud : itemSolicituds) {
            if (myDao.insertSolicitud(solicitud) == true){
                Crouton.makeText(Solicitudes.this, "Actualizado", Style.INFO).show();
                reload();
            }else {
                Crouton.makeText(Solicitudes.this, "Sin Novedades", Style.INFO).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
}
```

}

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: revisa si parseas correctamente el json e insertas lo valores al objeto.

Comment: He votado esta pregunta para cierre por el motivo siguiente: _Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o un error tipográfico._

Answer (score 0):

Faltan definir la parte esencial que es el parsear el .json, que en este caso es una Array e incluir los datos en el objeto `itemSolicitud`:

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(response);
JsonObject objeto = json.getJsonObject(0); //Indice del primer objeto, 0

String consesionario = objeto.getString("consesionario");
String cable_instalar = objeto.getString("cable_instalar");
String Tipo_Red = objeto.getString("Tipo_Red");
```

Los valores deben ser agregados al objeto `itemSolicitud`, mediante los `setters`, ejemplo:

```
itemSolicitud.setConsesionario(consesionario);
itemSolicitud.setCable_instalar(cable_instalar);
itemSolicitud.setTipo_Red(Tipo_Red);
```

Comment: el parseo si no me equivo se hace en el adapatador verdad?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente muchas gracias a los que me ayudaron, el error fue como en el mayor de los casos una palabra mal escrita y acompañada de una un elemento.

```
 public ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> getAllSolicitudes(){

    ArrayList<ItemSolicitud> lstSlicitud = new ArrayList<ItemSolicitud>();
    AD = DB.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor myCursor = AD.query(
            DataBase.TABLE_2,
            new String[]{"id","concesionario","cable_instalar","Tipo_Red"},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    if (myCursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            lstSlicitud.add(new ItemSolicitud(myCursor.getInt(0),
                    myCursor.getString(1), myCursor.getString(2), myCursor.getString(3)));
        }while (myCursor.moveToNext());
    }

    AD.close();
    return lstSlicitud;
}
```

Así la palabra concesionario estaba mal escrita en el JSON es por eso que aparecía como null porque no se encontraba, al igual que en mi cursor no había espacio para recorrer el arreglo y por ende no encontraba la posicion y la ponia como null.